# Strange exception with python's cgitb and inspect.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that decodes an exception and pushes the info to a file. Following is what I do basically:

```
exc_info = sys.exc_info
txt = cgitb.text(exc_info)
```

Using this, I got the following exception trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\job_queue\utils\start_workers.py", line 40, in start_worker
  worker_loop(r_jq, worktype, worker_id)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\job_queue\server\jq_worker.py", line 55, in worker_loop     
  _job_machine(*job)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\job_queue\server\jq_worker.py", line 34, in _job_machine
  do_verbose_exception()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\job_queue\server\errors.py", line 23, in do_verbose_exception
  txt = cgitb.text(exc_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\cgitb.py", line 214, in text
  formatvalue=lambda value: '=' + pydoc.text.repr(value))
File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 885, in formatargvalues
  specs.append(strseq(args[i], convert, join))
File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 840, in strseq
  return convert(object)
File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 882, in convert
  return formatarg(name) + formatvalue(locals[name])
KeyError: 'connection'
```

I ran the code multiple times after this exception, but couldn't reproduce it. However, I didn't find any reference in files cgitb.py or inspect.py to a dict with 'connection' key either.

Will anybody know if this is an issue with python's cgitb or inspect files? Any helpful inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure specifically why this exception is happening, but have you read the docs for cgitb module? It seems that since python 2.2 it has supported writing exceptions to a file:
http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html

Probably something like:
cgitb.enable(0, "/my/log/directory") # or 1 if you want to see it in browser

As far as your actual traceback, are you sure 'connection' isnt a name you are using in your own code? 'inspect' module is most likely trying to examine your own code to build the cgi traceback info and getting a bad key somewhere?

Comment: I crosschecked my codebase, and there is no 'connection' object in my codebase. Actually, I had run this after the crash with the same context, and it was successful. If you observer the crash log, line 882 shows 'locals[name]' and this crash is due to name -> connection. Still clueless, where from this had come.

Comment: I had gone through the cgitb code. Even using cgitb.enable with the log directory name will not solve this problem -- this happened while trying to decode the etraceback which is returned by sys.exc_info, which will be used there as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the issue. I use MySQLdb and the exception raised was using 'defaulthandler' (file: connections.py) where the 'connection' is deleted after raising the error. Don't know why that is done. However, I could workaround this using an exception handler around 'txt = cgitb.text(exc_info)', where I use 'traceback.format_exception'. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Ethan Can you please explain as an answer how you solved the issue, currently by reading your reply what i understood is: you now have a this txt line in try block and except is catching a format_exception exception, but what i don't understand is how it will solve the connection keyerror issue?

Comment: @MansoorAkram I would love to, but this is quite an old post and I don't have the code right now. Will reply if I get it. Sorry couldn't help here.

Answer (score 1):

You passed a wrong type to text function
below is the correct way.

cgitb.text((sys.last_type, sys.last_value, sys.last_traceback))